# Obter id de Object[]

Tags: java, array

Preciso pegar os id desse objetos.

```
Object[] classe = getNames().toArray();

String[] strings = Arrays.stream(classe ).map(Object::toString).
                toArray(String[]::new);

for (int i=0;i<strings.length;i++)
        {
            Integer id =strings[i].id;
        }
```

Teoricamente seria assim, porém não consigo pegar o id. No console me aparece o objeto todo.

Comment: Poste a classe que contém o tal `ìd` que você quer pegar. Forneça a maior quantidade possível de informações para que a comunidade possa se contextualizar quanto à sua dificuldade e te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Impossível do jeito que está fazendo já que seu array `String[] strings` é um `array` de `String` e a classe String nao possui uma propiedade id.